# SMTP protocol mail is not working using mail trap

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using smtp protocol to send mails using mailtrap. It is working perfectly in localhost but it is giving error. **Connection could not be established with host smtp.mailtrap.io [Connection refused #111].**

**.env**

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=********
MAIL_PASSWORD=********
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

**mail.php**

```
<?php
return [

    'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
    'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailtrap.org'),
    'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 2525,
    'from' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'hello@example.com'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Example'),
    ],
    'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
    'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),

    'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
    'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',

    'markdown' => [
        'theme' => 'default',

        'paths' => [
            resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
        ],
    ],

];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message means there is nothing listening on lort 2525 on server smtp.mailtrap.io.

I don t know mailtrap. Normally smtp servers listen on port 25, not port 2525.

Comment: Now  I am getting
Type error: Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Support\Manager::createDriver(), 0 passed in /home/bitlogicsolution/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Manager.php on line 88 and exactly 1 expected

Comment: Changing to port 25 worked?  If yes, please mark the answer as correct. Inspect line 88 and if you dont get the problem ask a new question

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your .env is still cached, please try to

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan cache:clear
```

Comment: This worked for me. Remember to also restart your server and re-serve artisan. Also you should be using 2525.